# Swift условие для появления кнопки

Tags: swift

У меня есть файл

```html
import SpriteKit


class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
var RestartBa : UIButton!
var RestartB : UIButton!
internal var ScoreL = UILabel()

internal var Score: NSInteger = 0 //передача внешней переменной


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


ScoreL.text = "\(Score)"
ScoreL = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20))
ScoreL.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
ScoreL.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.view?.addSubview(ScoreL)

if (Score == 2) {
self.view?.addSubview(RestartB)
}




scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
self.scene?.size = CGSize(width: 640, height: 1136)
// self.scene?.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)

RestartBa = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width / 3, height: 30))
RestartBa.center = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 2, view.frame.size.width / 3)
RestartBa.setTitle("1 Уровень", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
RestartBa.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
RestartBa.addTarget(self, action: Selector("Res"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view?.addSubview(RestartBa)



RestartB = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width / 3, height: 30))
RestartB.center = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 2, view.frame.size.width / 2)
RestartB.setTitle("2 Уровень", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
RestartB.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
RestartB.addTarget(self, action: Selector("Rest"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)



}

func Res(){

self.view?.presentScene(Start(), transition: SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.3))

let scene = Start(fileNamed: "GameScene")!
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.3))

RestartBa.removeFromSuperview()
RestartB.removeFromSuperview()
}

func Rest(){

self.view?.presentScene(copyGameScene(), transition: SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.3))

let scene = copyGameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")!
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.3))

RestartBa.removeFromSuperview()
RestartB.removeFromSuperview()
}

}
22:00:35
```

Получается при условии `if (Score == 2) {
self.view?.addSubview(RestartB)
}` 
у меня должна появляться кнопка, но на эту строчку появляется ошибка thread 1 exc_bad_instruction (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode = 0x0)
Что с этим сделать?спасибо.

Comment: тут все сломано :( на момент, когда вы пытаетесь добавить RestartB, он еще не существует. вы передаете ScoreL.text прямо перед тем, как создаете ScoreL, то есть text уходит вникуда, а уже потом создается ScoreL

Comment: а как тогда сделать наоборот?

Comment: честно говоря, надо садиться и читать книжки умные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Score передается до того, как ScoreL создан. надо передавать после создания:

```
ScoreL = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20))
ScoreL.text = "\(Score)"
ScoreL.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
ScoreL.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.view?.addSubview(ScoreL)
```

На момент, когда вы пытаетесь добавить RestartB он еще не существует. проверку надо делать после создания кнопки.

```
RestartB = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width / 3, height: 30))
RestartB.center = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 2, view.frame.size.width / 2)
RestartB.setTitle("2 Уровень", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
RestartB.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
RestartB.addTarget(self, action: Selector("Rest"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

if (Score == 2) {
    self.view?.addSubview(RestartB)
}
```

ну и по мелочи: переменные в swift/objC принято называть с маленькой буквы.

Comment: Вот как, спасибо, я почему-то думала, что в этом языке порядок не важен

Comment: не важен порядок объявления методов в классе, а порядок строк в методе важен во всех языках